# Не могу найти директорию imagemagick после ее установки

Tags: ubuntu, ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick

Установил imagemagick через `sudo apt install`, ошибок не дало, и пишет что успешно, пытаюсь установить гем rmagick, он не может найти директорию либы, поискав на форумах нашел инструкцию что надо в переменные среды экспортировать директорию нахождения файла MagicCore.pc , но `sudo find / -name MagickCore.pc` мне ничего не дает, а `which imagemagick` молчит. Вот что дает лог инсталла либы :

```
sudo apt install imagemagick
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
imagemagick is already the newest version (8:6.9.7.4+dfsg-16ubuntu6.4).
```

Собсна, где я запоролся?